# Node/Angularjs app not receiving JSON Web Token when using angularjs ui

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, json-web-token

I am making a MEAN stack application with authentication by JWT. This is the script which handles token authentication:

authenticationService.js

```
examApp.factory('authenticationService', ['$window', function ($window) {
var authToken = {};
var store = $window.localStorage;
var key = 'auth-token';
authToken.getToken = function () {
    return store.getItem(key);
}

authToken.setToken = function (token) {
    if (token) {
        store.setItem = (key, token);
    } else {
        store.removeItem(key);
    }
}

return authToken;}]);
```

Now, whenever i am logging into my application, the user/admin can log in successfully but in console, i am not receiving any tokens with token=null being displayed.

When i log in the application through POSTMAN tool and manually copy-pasting token after `token=` part in routes, i can perform any task, but logging in through angularjs ui, i get

> Token authentication failed

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try by fixing `store.setItem = (key, token);` to `store.setItem(key, token);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem in your code at

```
authToken.setToken = function (token) {
    if (token) {
        store.setItem = (key, token); // Here is the problem
    } else {
        store.removeItem(key);
    }
}
```

You are assigning the `store.setItem`, instead you need to execute `store.setItem` like below

```
authToken.setToken = function (token) {
    if (token) {
        store.setItem(key, token);
    } else {
        store.removeItem(key);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't know how something this simple passed by. Much thanks for pointing this out.